# Microsoft Sql ReportBuilder

Tags: ssrs-2008

I had downloaded the **Microsoft SQL Report Builder** and installed in my system. I designed the simple report with the help of Report Builder which contains one text box and saved it in D drive. Then I created the asp.net application and added the aspx page with Report Viewer. I had assigned the report to report viewer when I try to execute report is not loaded. I got the following error.

**The report definition is not valid.  Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded.**. I hope I make it clear.  Please do mail me if any one have Idea about this. MailId:sujibiit@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think its is possible.
There are a lot of websites that help out with this problem. You can refer SSRS 2016. here are some of the links i found useful.:

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/993309/The-report-definition-is-not-valid
[The report definition is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675248/the-report-definition-is-not-valid)

hope this helps.

Comment: Dear Shreeja,  I had tried this but my problem is not solved still I got the same error.